# translating a query on collections from SQL to nhibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, many-to-many, subquery

I have a database schema, where I have a `Product`, `Category`, `CategoryFeature`, and an `ProductCategoryFeatureValue`.

The Model is mapped using Fluent NHibernate, but basically is as follows.

```
Product
-------
ID
Title

Category
--------
ID
Title

CategoryFeature
---------------
ID
CategoryID
Title

ProductCategoryFeatureValue
---------------
ID
ProductID
CategoryFeatureID
_______________________

Category [one] <-> [many] CategoryFeature
Product [many] <-> [many] ProductCategoryFeatureValue
```

Basically, the features available to a product are listed in the `ProductCategoryFeatureValue` table, which is the 'middle-link' for the many-to-many collection.

I need to create a query, where i can find all products, which have ALL the features selected by the user.

Example, doing a search for two features with ids 643229 & 667811 in SQL terms, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product 
JOIN ProductCategoryFeatureValue AS feature1 ON Product.id = feature1.ProductID AND     feature1.categoryfeatureid = 643229
JOIN productcategoryfeaturevalue AS feature2 ON Product.id = feature2.ProductID AND feature2.categoryfeatureid = 667811
```

Another query which I could do is this:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE 
((SELECT id FROM productcategoryfeaturevalue AS feature1 WHERE feature1.ItemGroupID = product.id AND feature1.categoryFeatureID = 643229 LIMIT 1) IS     NOT NULL)
AND 
((SELECT id FROM productcategoryfeaturevalue AS feature2 WHERE feature2.ItemGroupID = product.id AND feature2.categoryFeatureID = 667811 LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL)
```

Both have been tested and work well. However, I cannot seem to reproduce them using NHibernate. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see how your object model is defined and mapped, that is what drives NHibernate's SQL generation.

Comment: Also, what method of NHibernate query are you looking for? Linq?, HQL?, QueryOver?

Comment: Queryover or Criteria, preferably without using any magic strings.

Comment: I've added the model information above, if it helps.  Exactly, it doesnt really matter how its mapped - It's not that its not working or something, its just that I dont know how to express that SQL query in any NH-flavor querying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this in SQL

```
Select *
from Products p
where p.id in (
   select fv.ProductId
   from ProductCategoryFeatureValue fv
   where fv.CategoryFeatureID in (643229,643230)
   group by fv.ProductId
   having count(*)=@NumberOfDistinctFeaturesSelected 
)
```

That will stop you having to JOIN to the ProductCategoryFeatureValue table multiple times for every feature selected by the user. At the very least your going to get a nicer query plan. If you don't like the IN clause you could also use a temp table instead.

In terms of translating this into NHibernate it doesn't support any HAVING clause logic in the Criteria API but it is supported using HQL.

[HQL Examples](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-12-hql-the-hibernate-query-language#)

```
var results = session.CreateQuery("from Product p where p.Id in (
    select fv.Product.Id
    from ProductCategoryFeatureValue fv
    where fv.CategoryFeature.Id in :featureids
    group by fv.Product.Id
    having count(fv)=:features
)")
.SetParameter("featureids", arrayOfFeatureIds)
.SetParameter("features", arrayOfFeatureIds.Count)
.List<Product>();
```

Comment: Is there any way to like 'combine' `HQL` and `Criteria`?  I wouldnt want to dump `Criteria API` for all the other conditions, because of this condition. I've managed to do it via HQL, although your solution seems to be more elegant having just one join, rather than one per feature selected.

It seems to me this type of condition is way more complicated to do than it should be - It's not such a rare type of condition on a query I guess?

Comment: Some things are just hard to do with the Criteria/QueryOver/Linq API's and in those exceptional cases like this one I would be happy to break out the HQL query to resolve the issue at hand. The only complicated thing about this query is the "must have all of the features selected" part. With the HQL version you get to keep the most performant SQL and still keep within the NHibernate context without having to drop down into stored procedures. Yeah I don't like the "magic string" elements of HQL either but if you keep the usage minimal I don't see too much of a downside.

Comment: I should also point out that in your SQL and the other solution provided you are going to generate a cartesian product out of the query results and potentially be sending more rows of data over the wire than you would like to. This gets exponentially worse depending on the number of features selected and the number of qualifying products found in the table.

Comment: Yes, but do you know if there is a way where you can create just one condition in HQL, leaving the rest using Criteria API?

Comment: No sorry, not something I have ever tried to do. You might be able to Criteria Query the outer part of the query (Select * from Product) but the subquery part will need to be HQL. If you are worried about the "magic strings" you could always do some expression based reflection to build up the text of the query which would still give you some refactoring support.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure from the question exactly what your mappings are but this may be close to what you need

```
object[] featureIds = new object[2];

featureIds[0] = 643229;
featureIds[1] = 667811;

ICriteria criteria = base.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product));
criteria.CreateAlias("ProductCategoryFeatureValueList", 
"ProductCategoryFeatureValue", JoinType.InnerJoin);
criteria.CreateAlias("ProductCategoryFeatureValue.CategoryFeatureID", 
"CategoryFeature", JoinType.InnerJoin);

criteria.Add(Expression.In("CategoryFeature.ID", featureIds));
```

If the "Expression.In" doesn;t quite do what you are after you could just do a quick loop adding

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("CategoryFeature.ID", featureIds[i]));
```

Comment: I will check it out later on, but I've already tried a similar route, and a `criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("CategoryFeature.ID", featureIds[i]))` will result in always false, as an ID can never be two values at once.

Comment: Ah, I've just tried it with some tables I am more familar with but have a similar structure and can see your problem.  I'll have a play around with NHibernate and get back to you.

Comment: Won't this type of query result in duplicate Product rows being returned?

Answer (score 0):

I think your biggest problem is adding a condition on a join.  I haven't tried it yet, but have been looking forward to the feature of NH 3.+ that lets you add a criteria join.

CreateAlias(string associationPath, string alias, JoinType joinType, ICriterion withClause) CreateCriteria(string associationPath, string alias, JoinType joinType, ICriterion withClause)

Comment: It *could* be done this way with loop to add extra joins but I think that is going to under perform (due to exponential joins) rather than use the HQL version.